# How do I run powershell from within VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Hope someone can help. I want to run powershell but can't see any menu item to run it.

Am I missing something. I looked in view > other windows but nothing there.

Janet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such default menu item.

You can always [create your own](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/29/customize-your-toolbars-in-visual-studio-2010-commands-tab-vstipenv0031.aspx) under `Tools -> Customize`.

Alternatively, use [this](http://vscmdshell.codeplex.com/) Visual Studio plugin, which will give you a shell window (either CMD or PowerShell).

Comment: Surely there must be something easier :-(  Is there something I can add from the command-line?

Comment: @Janet - This is _not_ difficult.

Comment: Okay. I will check into it in more details. Thanks for the advice / link.

Comment: Janet, you might actually consider installing [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/). It's the 'new' package manager for VS2010 and has a rather nice PowerShell command interface.